# Contact Form 7 List Building

Tags: custom-field, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

i'm Graphic Designer and I was recently  hired as a front-end at an agency. There I have a lot of demand for landing page with forms. I currently create forms with contact form 7 and the newsletter plugin. I know it's possible to create custom fields and I've made them. But I do not completely understand how to save the data from these custom fields.

Today I found a plugin that might work as I need but I'm still testing, it's called "cfdbplugin.com".
If anyone can give me a light I would be very pleased.
PS: For example, in CF7 we can create radios buttons but i dont know how to store this data. I can send it by e-mail but i would like to keep it in a database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Edit regarding **lists**:

If you are just talking about collecting emails and other info for lists, and those persons are not intended to be users of the site, I would look into posting your form to the service that will be handling the list. Any of the major services would have tutorials regarding *"hosting your own sign up form"*.

In your form, the `action` attribute would be a link they provide.

```
<form action="http://some-link-privided-by-sevice/" method="POST">
```

And the `name` attributes of the input field(s) would correspond to some value on their end as well, since their script would be handling the data submitted.

```
<input type="text" name="the-name-they-want" value="" />
```

There will also be some hidden fields required to pass a secret key of some kind generated on their end.
(An example from the service Mailchimp):

```
    <form action="http://mailchimp.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="u" value="a123cd45678ef90g7h1j7k9lm">

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="ab2c468d10">
    //your input fields
   //submit button
   </form>
```

### Getting Form Data in General

If posting the form to a function of your own, you access those input fields as parts of the $_POST array:

```
if (isset ($_POST['u'] ) ) { 
   //do stuff with set value 
}
```

Within wordpress you can utilize `wp_ajax_nopriv` for non-logged in users when posting a form to admin-ajax.php: `action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"`

See the linked tutorial below about posting from the front end to adapt it to your needs if that's case.

### Other Data Collection

With collecting data from forms, you are, essentially, talking about posting from the frontend of the site.
Something like [this tutorial on posting from the frontend](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/posting-via-the-front-end-inserting--wp-27034) should get you in the right direction. The wp-api could be leveraged for this as well (not sure if that tutorial gets into it that or not).

**Some more details and things to keep in mind:**
I can't speak on the particular plugin you mentioned, but in terms of saving form data to the wordpress database, there are a couple things to consider. Most importantly: 
[Validating, Sanitizing, and Escaping](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and the use of [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)

Saving the form entry from the frontend is creating a new post, and adding those custom fields to that post (custom fields are just post meta keys/values). So in addition to [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), it would use [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

To easily exclude this type of posting from other posts, I usually relegate it to a specific [custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) for organizational purposes.